# How to save the last selected language?

Tags: android, string, android-studio, android-activity, multilingual

I am adding multiple language facility in my android app.
Whenever I change the language it changes fine. But after reopening the app its again showing the choose language screen.
I want to save the last selected language, so next time when user reopen the app it should not show the choose language screen it should directly go to the next page and should display the items in the language which was last selected.
What to do? Any solutions?
Please check the below code.
In this code 
where i have to store in SharedPreferences and where i have to get the sharedpreference

@Override
    public void onItemSelected(SelectableItem selectableItem) {

```
    List<Item> selectedItems = adapter.getSelectedItems();

if(selectableItem.getName().equals("English")){
    if (userSessionManager.isLoggedIn()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LanguageListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(intent);

        setLanguage("en");

    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LanguageListActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        Log.d("Login", "firgage");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(intent);
       setLanguage("en");

    }


 }else if(selectableItem.getName().equals("Hindi(हिंदी)")){
    if (userSessionManager.isLoggedIn()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LanguageListActivity.this, MainHindiActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(intent);
        setLanguage("hi");

    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LanguageListActivity.this, LoginhindiActivity .class);
        Log.d("hLogin", "firhin");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(intent);
       setLanguage("hi");
        String lang = "hi";

    }

 }
```

}

```
protected void setLanguage(String language){
    mylocale=new Locale(language);
    Resources resources=getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm=resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf= resources.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale=mylocale;
    resources.updateConfiguration(conf,dm);
    //Intent refreshIntent=new Intent(LanguageListActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    finish();
    //startActivity(refreshIntent);
}
```

Comment: Save it in some sort of a config file.. If your application has a login feature, then you can save as the user preference.

Comment: share your code

Comment: save it in preference and then get once you back to app

Comment: Save chosen language in shared preference.

Comment: In your code when you are adding         `setLanguage("hi");` add my answer of store in sharedpreference by storing hi to shared preference

Comment: @rahul In first activity of your applicaton. from where you will redirect to language screen or main screen.

Comment: @Vishva Dave if my last selected lang english then also when i reopens the app hindi is showing

Comment: @rahul check sharedpreference value by log that it stored en or hi.

Comment: @Vishva Dave  your answer was helpful but you should have declare the "language"  like String language  = "hi"; // your language,in your code but you didnt declare the language which was bit confusing but otherwise it was helpful,Thanks

Comment: @rahul sorry for that. Happy to help :) happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to save the last selected language - For this you need to use **SharedPreferences**

For SharedPreferences reference : [shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#GetSharedPreferences)

To store in SharedPreferences :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("lang", language);
editor.commit();
```

To get the SharedPreferences :

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
       MY_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String language = sharedPref.getString("lang", null);
```

Check in activity onCreate that if this shared preference is null or not. if null then language screen and if not null then home screen.

**Tutorial** : [SharedPreferences](https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial)

[More about SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/8089770)